What are the relevant resources or topics to learn (in order) have a strong foundation in Python for beginners - intermediate?
I have already learnt some basics and some projects but I feel like my foundation is all over the place. So I need your expert and experienced guidance.
P.N. by resources or topic I meant like learn arrays, generators, functions and some advanced way to use it and so on.
My main issue is that I can't seem to gather previous knowledge, identify the problem and find a solution- I know these are the essence of programming. :)
I tried a lot of YouTube tutorials, but facing the same problem with some twists puzzles me into despair.

It seems to me that you're thinking about programming as puzzles with clever solutions, when really the basics are mastered through simple repetition.  Many good programmers begin to learn their craft by tinkering and building many small projects.  Build a model of population growth.  Build a nice little UI for Conway's Game of Life.  Build a small game.  Build a website that uses weather APIs to compare the weather in two different places.  Build a website that makes anagrams out of names.
It almost doesn't matter what you build - just keep building lots and lots of small projects, and you will find that many of the ways of thinking about programming begin to seep into you, and you will find that your confidence grows, and this will give you a good basis to begin your intermediate to advanced explorations of software development.

I'd like to add: find someone (experienced in professional Python-based software development) who reviews your projects and gives you advice how to improve your solutions. If you don't know someone, you could use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
